# Magento 2 - Not Receiving Email After Order

Tags: magento2.4, order-email, server-setup

I have this demo Magento 2 store (ver. 2.4.4) built on a Debian server and for some reason I'm not receiving emails after I make an order.

In Stores > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails I have this:

[image: sales emails configurations]

My /etc/postfix/main.cf file:

[image: main.cf]

I didn't even receive an email when I first installed Magento 2 on my server, so I had to disable the 2FA module in order to login to the backend for the first time.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

This is what the mail logs show:

[image]

Comment: Please check your cron and indexer settings and try to again run them manually once and check in the email logs if they are successful or not. and if the issue still persists can you please share us the log files related to this issue so that it will make debugging easier.Thanks

Comment: Hi @BharathKumarJ thank you for your reply. The indexers seem to be fine, there's no warning or anything. This is what my logs look like: https://postimg.cc/v1gJKn97

Answer (score 0):

Based on those logs it looks as though you're using google as an SMTP service, and that appears to be timing out / blocking your request.

Maybe try port 587 or 465, rather than 25.

Comment: How do I change the port? I tried navigating to Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System, changed the port there and made another order, but in the logs it still shows that it's trying to reach port 25... so how do I change the port? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I would change the port in postfix if that's how you've connected to googles smtp